# Changing Filter Parameter for Specific CSS File in Just React

Tags: css, reactjs, filter, dynamic, slider

I want to change my app color dynamicly with using filter color and slider.

I have to use this:

```
*{
    filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

this codes, and this code working with `App.css` and `index.css`, other methods not works like

```
#root{
        filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
    }
```

How can i handle this.
I need to use vanila react,

I want same thing like this site`s Filter Functions area
*https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it done,

You need to add gradient to Main Component like App.js

and add style like this
`<div className="App" style={{filter: colors}}>`

Slider example

```
<div className="slider"><Slider min={0} max={360} defaultValue={0} onChange={(e)=>(setHue(e.target.value))} /></div>
```

This is setHue func

```
const setHue = (e)=>{
    setColor(e)
    setColors('hue-rotate('+color+'deg)')

  }
```

setColor will get data from slider and this color will go to setColors and colors will go to `style={{filter: **colors**}}`